# Constructing an if, if else, else statement

Tags: php

```
/* Errors exist, have user correct them */
    if($form->num_errors > 0)
    {
         return 1;  //Errors with form
    }
     /* No errors, add the new account to the */
    else if($database->addLeagueInformation($subname, $subformat, $subgame, $subseason, $subwindow, $subadmin, $subchampion, $subtype))
    {
        $database->addLeagueTable();
        $_SESSION['players'] == $subplayers;
        $comp_name == '$format_$game_$name_$season';
        $_SESSION['comp_name'] == $comp_name;
        return 0;  //New user added succesfully
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;  //Registration attempt failed
    }
```

At the moment this isn't doing any of these things:

```
$database->addLeagueTable();
    $_SESSION['players'] == $subplayers;
    $comp_name == '$format_$game_$name_$season';
    $_SESSION['comp_name'] == $comp_name;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Editing!

```
$comp_name = "$subformat_$subgame_$subname_$subseason";
        $_SESSION['comp_name'] = $comp_name;
```

This code is only generating whats in $subseason?
Is there an obvious reason for this?

Further editing!

```
else if($database->addLeagueInformation($subname, $subformat, $subgame, $subseason, $subwindow, $subadmin, $subchampion, $subtype))
    {
        $_SESSION['players'] = $subplayers;
        $comp_name = "$subformat_$subgame_$subname_$subseason";
        $_SESSION['comp_name'] = $comp_name;
        $database->addLeagueTable();
        return 0;  //New user added succesfully
    }
```

And the function addLeagueTable()

```
function addLeagueTable() {
   $q = "CREATE TABLE `$_SESSION[comp_name]` (
     `user` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
        `team` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
        `home_games_played` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `home_wins` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `home_draws` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `home_losses` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `home_points` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `home_goals_for` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `home_goals_against` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `away_games_played` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `away_wins` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `away_draws` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `away_losses` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `away_points` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `away_goals_for` INT( 3 ) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `away_goals_against` INT( 3 )  NULL DEFAULT '0'
        )";
   return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

any ideas?

How i pass..

```
      $retval = $session->createLeague($_POST['name'], $_POST['players'], $_POST['format'], $_POST['game'], $_POST['season'], $_POST['window'], $_POST['admin'], $_POST['champion'], $_POST['type']);
```

And this sends them to the function the addLeagueInformation is sent to!

Answer (score 5):

== is a comparison operator but e.g. in `$_SESSION['players'] == $subplayers;` you want the assignment operator =
Maybe you also have an issue with `$comp_name == '$format_$game_$name_$season';`. In single-quoted strings php does not substitute variables.

Comment: And the same goes for the following several lines

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Actually perform the assignments?

```
$_SESSION['players'] = $subplayers;
// ------------------^ one '=' instead of two '==' (which is for comparison).
$comp_name = "{$format}_{$game}_{$name}_{$season}";
// double quotes to allow substitution,
// {...} to avoid interpreting the variable name as `$format_`.
$_SESSION['comp_name'] = $comp_name;
```

And make sure `addLeagueInformation` really return a non-false value in your test if you expect them to be executed.

Comment: This helped, but i dont think $comp_name = '$format_$game_$name_$season';
is working?

Comment: @Luke: You need double quotes.

Comment: @Luke: Updated answer. And see also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.

Comment: That has stopped it working. I will provide more code in my question.

Comment: Edited question further...those {} ended up giving me just underscores!

Comment: @Luke: How did you implement `addLeagueInformation`? Are you passing the arguments by reference (See http://hk2.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)?

Comment: I will add how I pass in the question

Comment: Try `$comp_name = "${format}_${game}_${name}_$season";`. PHP may be picking up the _ as part of the name, and you need double quotes for variables to be expanded within the string.